# Can't create a bucket with my domain name

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I just turned on Google Cloud Storage and was going to create a bucket to test a static website with our domain. When I tried to create the bucket with our www.*ourdomain.com* I received the following message:

The bucket you tried to create is a domain name owned by another user.

From the documentation that I read, it appears that any bucket that has a dot or is a domain needs to be verified by the domain owner (me), which I know I have not done with Google Storage. I've owned the domain for a couple years and I am the only one with access to GS.

Are we out of luck using our own domain name on Google Storage?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can use [Google Webmaster Central](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification) or [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console) to get your domain ownership verified.

Or your friend/colleague can use these sites to add you as an owner of the domain if they have already verified themselves as owners first.

---

## There is one caveat with ServiceAccounts though.

When we want to use Google ServiceAccounts to create/manage GCS buckets, we have to add the ServiceAccount email as an owner of that domain first.

However, adding the **ServiceAccount email** via [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console) only adds it as a **"Delegated User"** of the domain and not as an **"Owner"** of the domain - don't know why.

Until now, a ServiceAccount can be added as an **"Owner"** only via [Google Webmaster Central](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification).

Comment: I am trying to add a service account email. In the google webmaster central it only add the email as a Delegation. Can u tell me how you were able to add the email as an owner

Comment: Thanks! Adding the app engine service account email address to Google Webmaster Central worked great.

Answer (score 9):

Following https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/domain-name-verification :

To verify as the owner or manager of a domain, use the Google Webmaster Tools verification process. The Webmaster Tools verification process provides three methods for verifying an owner or manager of a domain:

Adding a special Meta tag to a site's homepage.
Uploading a special HTML file to a site.
Adding a DNS TXT record to a domain's DNS configuration.

Comment: Additionally, if you are using an api to create the bucket automagically, the service account needs to be added as an additional owner to the verified domain in webmaster tools.

Comment: Trying to add the service account in the format of foo@bar.iam.gserviceaccount.com gets me: We could not find a Google Account for foo@bar.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Any tips?

Comment: I had to add the service account to both https://search.google.com/search-console/users and https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/details

Comment: @kvz I got that same error, so I removed all leading and trailing whitespace then it worked.

Comment: heh, you would think the guys at google would strip() text input for lookup

Answer (score 1):

Verify the domain with any of the ways you can do to verify your ownership. Then wait for 24hrs and then try your bucketname. If you dont get it done then raise a ticket and you will get the bucket name very soon.

Comment: where can you raise a ticket?